# Add pointer arrow classes for all sides of the div centered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add arrows to my div similar to that you would see on a tooltip, I need separate classes that I can add to the main div that will then put an arrow centered on the div, either left, right, top or bottom.

I need the arrows to to be centered regardless of the width / height of the div.

Here is what I have so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hRMgk/1/

Full CSS, HTML and jQuery on the fiddle

```
<div id="theHover" class="therequest">
 <div class="noprint">
    <button  id="closetheHover">Close Window</button>
 </div>
        You need to start here on the website.
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `arrows`?

Comment: demo doesn't give any indication of what you need without understanding what `arrows` are

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about triangles in the chat bubbles which are very much frequent in many applications... Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Cg7k9/) which i think you are interested in.. 
I just added this to your css :

```
 #theHover.arrow::before
 {
content:'';
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:100%;
border:12px solid black;
border-color:Blue transparent transparent transparent;
}
#theHover.arrow::after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
left:51%;
top:100%;
border:10px solid black;
 border-color:white transparent transparent transparent; 
}
```

This is done basically by using the before content and after content property in CSS... You can get more info from this [site](http://forrst.com/posts/How_to_Make_a_Pure_CSS_Speech_Bubble_With_a_Drop-PU1)...

Comment: Yes this is what I need similar to speech bubbles, few things though. How do you get left, right and top arrows as different classes? It also the arrow doesnt seem to be quiet in the middle. http://jsfiddle.net/Cg7k9/1/ thanks for the reply! :-)

Comment: If you look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cg7k9/) which i have made then I have tried to keep the arrow properties in a different class and then I have added the class through jquery.addClass()... Is this what you were asking?

Comment: And feel free check mark on the answer which I have given you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Kelly,

add code in the css (#hover)

```
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/hRMgk/18/

Good luck !